# git: getting rid of previous commit so that you can amend the one before

Tags: git, git-amend

what happened:
change1,
git commit,
git push,
change2,
git commit

what should have happened:
change1,
git commit,
git push,
change2,
git commit **--amend**

It's not important that I retain change2, but it is important that I am able to amend the original commit. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have pushed it, be aware that this is tricky and you are rewriting history.

You can `git rebase -i` to before the first commit and choose `edit` for the commit in the text that is presented to you. This way, you will be brought to the first commit state where you change / amend and then git will apply the next commit over it.

Or you can `git reset --soft first` to go to first commit and amend it along with change2.

Or `git reset --hard first` to go to the first commit and amend it without the change2

Answer (score 0):

[I assume you know that Linus thinks this is evil]

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^  # remove last commit
$ git commit --amend
$ git push --force <remote> <branch>
```

If you want the last commit to be applied afterward, then do

```
$ SHA1=`git rev-parse master`
$ git branch temp
# now the three commands above
$ git cherry-pick $SHA1
$ git branch -d temp
```